# Confluence "Hello World" Macro help - NPM install/start not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, confluence

I am trying to make my first confluence macro and I am following the instructions laid out here:https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/confluence/getting-started/?_ga=2.78735767.2027190294.1547046060-2004234667.1546438516

Currently, I am having trouble with steps 2 and 4; NPM install and NPM start:

Received the following errors:

```js
➜  ~ cd confluence_app
➜  confluence_app 
➜  confluence_app ls
confluence-helloworld-addon credentials.json            package-lock.json
➜  confluence_app ls
confluence-helloworld-addon
➜  confluence_app cd confluence-helloworld-addon
➜  confluence-helloworld-addon git:(master) npm install package.json 
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
+ package.json@2.0.1
added 74 packages from 35 contributors and audited 162 packages in 29.12s
found 0 vulnerabilities

➜  confluence-helloworld-addon git:(master) ✗ npm start               

> helloworld-addon@0.0.1 start /Users/serdarmustafa/confluence_app/confluence-helloworld-addon
> node app.js

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:583
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'express'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/serdarmustafa/confluence_app/confluence-helloworld-addon/app.js:6:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! helloworld-addon@0.0.1 start: `node app.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the helloworld-addon@0.0.1 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/serdarmustafa/.npm/_logs/2019-01-12T09_26_18_269Z-debug.log
```

Comment: first run "npm install" or "npm i" that installs all the required dependencies for your project.. then run the project again

Comment: @gopigorantala the OP did run npm install…

Comment: Did below answer fixed your issue.. ?

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, employer decided to abandon confluence so I won't b continuing with this. Sorry for such a bad post.

Answer (score 0):

run `npm cache clean --force` first, and then run `npm install`, then `npm start`

this should fix it..

-- 
OR delete the node_modules folder and re-run `npm install`

--
OR 
1. npm cache clean --force

2. delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`,
3. npm install

Comment: Still no joy... Tried all of the above, tried uninstalling all of node and reinstall but still nothing. At this stage thinking, I am being a total newb and doing something really wrong.

Comment: ^Did this but no change. Seems Atlassian is making some GDPR related changes in their end with the API's, think that might have something to do with it.